# Angular 5 - how to reload current data when I use RouteReuseStrategy

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using RouteReuseStrategy to control of route snapshot caching, it is working fine going to another component from my search component and when I click "back" I have the old(search) component there like was. The problem is, if I go to another component and edit some value and back to search, that value edited still the old one and not the new one. How can I use the current data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell your router how to behave on your component.

Start by telling him to propagate routing events in your component with

```js
this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
```

Next, tell him to do something on routing events, particularly on the last event

```js
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
  if (!(event instanceof NavigationEnd)) { return; }
  // Do what you need to do here, for instance : 
  ngOnInit();
});
```

Comment: Always here to help !